# Are gay people in this life still gay in the afterlife?

Tags: jannah, homosexuality, akhirah

Today I was talking to a homosexual friend of mine and I'm a devoted Muslim, but I could not answer their question because I, myself, do not know the answer! I was really confused so I told them I'd ask around and get back to their question.

Questions are,

Are gay/lesbian men and women gay/lesbian in the next life?

Does this mean lesbian women can get any woman they want in the next and gay men can as well?

Allah says people can have whatever they want in heaven, so does this mean it is okay?

If they abstained from their homosexual urges and desires in this life, would Allah SWT grant them free choice over their desires in the Akhira?

I'm not saying it's wrong, but now even I am genuinely curious because I've never actually researched this topic.